# MS Access link record from forms

Tags: forms, ms-access, between, correlated

There are two tables, one for Student and one for Borrowed Books. In the Microsoft Access (2010, 2013), it is easy to display a form Student based on the table Student, and other form BorrowedBooks based on the table Borrowed Books with their Record Source pointed.

How to do Form BorrowedBooks showing records for the current student showing on the Form Student one at one time? I'm looking to learn both VBA script and using the built-in controls to achieve the result.

Relationship between has been built. And it's one student to many books relationship.

Comment: Please post what you have so far so we can get some more context

Comment: I have two tables with records saved in the Access database, and I have two forms each table created and each form has "Record Source" pointed to their respective table. As stated, relationship is also built.

Comment: I also just tried "Form_BorrowedBooks.CurrentRecord=Form_Student.CurrentRecord" under Form_Load of BorrowedBooks. And it got error of '2455'. "You entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the property CurrentRecord."

Answer (score 0):

One VBA approach like:

`DoCmd.OpenForm "BorrowedBooks", , , "StudentID = " & Me.StudentID`

The real trick is figuring out which event to put code into.

Another option is to use form/subform arrangement - main form bound to Students table and subform bound to BorrowedBooks. Have you looked at Microsoft Lending Library database template?

Comment: "Me" is meaning its own form/control, right? Or you meant putting the event under the Form load event of Students? <br/> I saw another option online as you mentioned, but I was asked to develop as two forms separately instead of putting together as form/subform. <br/> I will look at the template too. Thanks.

Comment: "Me" is alias for form full name. You would open BorrowedBooks from Students so the suggested code goes behind Students.

Answer (score 0):

so if my understanding of your question is clear then you need to join operation on the tables

SELECT * 
FROM
student
INNER JOIN borrowedbooks ON (The two table'S related column ie student.pk=borrowedbooks.fk)

you can also add a where clause if you want from here you can state you primary key in student table and it relationshi